# Polymorphism constructor function

Tags: c++, inheritance

My code compiles fine but I am having issues with a particular section not displaying the correct output.

Here is my base class

```
class Item
 {
 protected:

//int count;
string model_name;
int item_number;

 public:

Item();
Item(string name, int number);
     string getName(){return model_name;}
int getNumber(){return item_number;}
```

and here is my derived class:

```
 class Bed : public Item
 {
 private:

string frame;
string frameColour;
string mattress;

 public:

 Bed();

 Bed(int number, string name, string frm, string fclr, string mtres);
```

Function definitions:

```
 Bed::Bed(int number, string name, string frm, string fclr, string mtres)
{
model_name=name;
item_number=number;
frame=frm;
frameColour=fclr;
mattress=mtres;
cout<<model_name<<item_number<<frame<<frameColour<<mattress<<endl;
}
```

Main section that is causing the problem:

```
 Item* item= new Bed(number, name, material, colour, mattress);
 cout<<"working, new bed"<<endl;
 v.push_back(item);
 cout<<"working pushback"<<endl;
 cout<<" this is whats been stored:"<<endl;
 cout<<v[count]->getName<<endl;
 cout<<v[count]->getNumber<<endl;
 count++;
```

when the programme executes, the cout within the constructor shows the correct output, but when I call getname and getnumber from the main function the programme prints '1' for both , no matter what's stored in there.
I thought that derived classes could use base class methods, what have I missed?
Any help would be great

thanks 
Hx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks incorrect (and I am unsure how this even compiled):

```
cout<<v[count]->getName<<endl;
cout<<v[count]->getNumber<<endl;
```

as `getName` and `getNumber` are methods. Change to:

```
cout<<v[count]->getName()<<endl;
cout<<v[count]->getNumber()<<endl;
```

Additionally, the initialisation of `count` is not posted: ensure it is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you example is not related to polymorphism. The reason here is that you are not using any virtual functions. Here is the code that you can use.

```
class Item
{
protected:

    std::string model_name;
    int item_number;

public:

    Item();
    Item(std::string& name, int number) : model_name(name), item_number(number) {};
    std::string getName(){return model_name;}
    int getNumber(){return item_number;}
};

class Bed : public Item
{
private:

    std::string frame;
    std::string frameColour;
    std::string mattress;

public:

    Bed();

    Bed(int number, std::string& name, std::string& frm, std::string& fclr, std::string& mtres) : Item(name, number), 
                                                                                                  frame(frm),
                                                                                                  frameColour(fclr), 
                                                                                                  mattress(mtres) {};
};

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<Item*> v;

    Item* item = new Bed(2, std::string("MyBed"), std::string("wood"), std::string("red"), std::string("soft"));
    std::cout << "working, new bed" << std::endl;
    v.push_back(item);

    std::cout << "working pushback" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " this is whats been stored:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[count]->getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[count]->getNumber() << std::endl;

    ++count;

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` appears to be the size of your `vector`. After you push back the last element, you're not incrementing `count`, so you're printing an older element.

Why don't you try:

```
cout<<v[v.size()-1]->getName<<endl;
cout<<v[v.size()-1]->getNumber<<endl;
```

Also, you should start using initialization lists in your constructors:

```
Bed::Bed(int number, string name, string frm, string fclr, string mtres) :
  Item(name,number),
  frame(frm),
  frameColour(fclr),
  mattress(mtres)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the base class's constructor from the derived class... Where as it should be the first line... update the code, I am sure it will start working..

**EDIT**

If it doesn't than you should probably also check the way you are handling count variable... as pointed out by others..

Comment: Actually, the default constructor of the base class is called. And the base members are assigned to in the derived constructor body.

Comment: Still you should use initialization method suggested by @Lucian... your problem solved or not ?